# Dr. Racket does not work properly

Tags: 14.04

I just installed Dr. Racket Version 5.3.6 on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (32 bit) machine. The installation completed successfully but when I tried to start Dr. Racket it doesn't appear. The progress bar showing the loading of the program appears but the screen doesn't. Can anyone help to rectify my problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a more recent version on the [official website](http://download.racket-lang.org/). Hopefully it'll fix your issue.